# How to write a mongo $all $in query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Please help with a mongodb query. I need to check that all array items in another array.
I need something like the following -

```
db.getCollection('Transactions').find({
    BusinessUnitids: { 
        $all: { $in: [item1, item2, item3] } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: try removing $in from your query db.testcoll.find({'arr1':{$all:['A','B']}}..ensures arr1 has all the items of given ['A','B'] array. Is this what you are looking for

Comment: Not exactly. I need to select all documents, where some array is superset of document property. With LINQ I would write something like this - list.Where(x=>x.Array.All(a=>superset.Contains(a)))

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for unique values (e.g. ignoring that either array can have repeating values like [1,1,2,3]), then you can use [$setEquals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/#exp._S_setEquals).

For example:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id": 0, "a": [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

> db.test.aggregate([{$project: {set_equal: {$setEquals: ['$a', [1, 2, 3]]}}}])
{ "_id": 0, "set_equal": true }

> db.test.aggregate([{$project: {set_equal: {$setEquals: ['$a', [1, 2, 3, 4]]}}}])
{ "_id": 0, "set_equal": false }
```

If you require other set operations, please see [Set Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/).

Note that set operations are part of the [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and not part of the regular `find()` command.